# Two questions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

1. How do I define in SQL Server in datatype field with fixed data (like `SELECT` in html) of my choice?
2. How to set column, which does not allow a number greater than 50, in Management Studio??

Thanks!

Comment: For second question you can try check constraint. link(https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp).

Describe first question for more understanding.

Comment: Please try to keep your posts focused and ask only one question per post.

Comment: @Somendra Kanaujia in Management Studio??

Comment: For datatype reference [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this post contains two questions (Which is usually a problem in Q & A websites), I believe that the answer to both question can be the same (otherwise I wouldn't post this answer to begin with) - but that's assuming I understand the first question - which is basically how to define a column that can only contain a limited set of options (like a dropdown or an enum).

Based on that assumption, and also assuming we're not talking about a very large list of values, both questions can be answered by using a check constraint.

In SQL Server, a check constraint validates data that is attempted to be entered into a table (either by `insert` or by `update`), and throws an exception if the check returns false.

So, Limiting the set of values a column can take in is a good candidate for a check constraint - unless we're talking about a very large list of values, which makes it cumbersome to write and maintain and is usually better covered using a foreign key.

So, assuming I want a table that have two columns - one a string that can only have the values `yes`, `no`, `black` and `white`, and the other an int that can have values between 0 and 50 (inclusive) I would write it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DemoTable 
(
    Enum varchar(5),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_DemoTable_Enum CHECK (Enum IN('Yes', 'No', 'Black', 'White')),
    Number tinyint,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_DemoTable_Number CHECK (Number >= 0 AND Number <= 50)
);
```

You can see a live demo on <kbd>[rextster](https://rextester.com/JOHO5412)</kbd>.